# Difference between an Enum and a List in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I read that enums are used for defining named constant values. But I dont get how it is different from a list in dart. Anyone cares to explain?

Comment: Where did you read that? Enums are not the same as lists, but if you share a link to where you saw that I'd be happy to explain what they mean.

Comment: Just explain what it means in your own words @BenKonyi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An enum is used for defining named constants values. Constant values in the sense that once it is defined, it cannot be added to, removed or changed just as a const variable.

While a List on the other hand, is used to store objects too. Which can be manipulated such as add, remove and change the values in the list. Which is not allowed on enum.

Answer (score 1):

Enum is a user-defined data type. The built-in enum in dart stores an index, and a name with a string value.

Lists, on the other hand, can store objects. You can also add, remove and change values in lists, however, this is not allowed on enum.